# Delegate Bash completion of function to command with additional arguments

Tags: bash, kubectl, bash-completion

I'm trying to enable Bash completion for my own function called `kctxt()` that delegates to `kubectl` as follows:

```sh
kctxt() {
  if [[ -z ${1+x} ]]; then
    # show context if no arguments
    kubectl config current-context
  else
    # set new context via completion
    kubectl config use-context "$@"
  fi
}

# For example, get completions just like:
# kubectl config use-context <tab><tab>

$ kctxt <tab><tab>
minikube eks-kube
$ kctxt ▊
```

First, I want to add that the standard completion for `kubectl` is working just fine for me on macOS, and I have even installed [`complete-alias`](https://github.com/cykerway/complete-alias) to match `alias k=kubectl`.

Is there a **generic way** to delegate the completion of a custom function to another command that also includes additional arguments? I've consulted many answers to similar questions that delegate a **subcommand** for another, like `exec` and `time`, but all I can get is completion on the main command.

I've also tried to define a custom completion function like this, and delegate to `__start_kubectl()` (per `complete -p kubectl`) without success.

```sh
_complete_kctxt() {
  COMPREPLY=()

  COMP_WORDS=(config use-context $2)
  COMP_LINE="kubectl ${COMP_WORDS[@]}"

  local prev=${COMP_WORDS[$COMP_CWORD]}
  local cur=${COMP_WORDS[$((++COMP_CWORD))]}

  COMP_POINT=${#COMP_LINE}
  [[ -z "$cur" ]] && ((++COMP_POINT))

  __start_kubectl kubectl $cur $prev
}
complete -F _complete_kctxt kctxt
```

I even tried to trace the completion of `kubectl` via `BASH_COMP_DEBUG_FILE` but that's pretty difficult to comprehend.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to define your command that way?

```
alias kctxt="kubectl config current-context"
```

It works for me with other aliases having `bash-completion` installed.
The alias in `.bash_aliases` and that line in `.bash_completion`

```
complete -F _complete_alias kctxt
```